# Formatting Text Data from one Column into Multiple columns

Tags: sql, excel, powerbi

I have been working on this for 2 days and I have no had luck finding out how to do this.

I have a single column that contains data that I need to format.

Here is an image showing what I'm looking for. I'm using Excel 2013 and MS SQL Server 2012 Enterprise. I have the latest version of Power BI.

[What I have What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rLJY.png)

I haven't dealt with data in this type of format before and I'm not a SQL guru so I'm looking for some help. I can't find anything online that is similar to my situation. I will use any tool that can do this. I've tried Excel, SQL, Power BI with no luck so far. I'm sure its something simple.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I suggest you use VBA.  Once you have developed some code, if you have problems post back here with specific questions. This is not a free code-writing service but exists to help others with code or functions they are trying to develop.  As such, we expect to see clear cut questions with examples of data, attempted code, actual output, desired output, research efforts to solve the problem, etc.  Please read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); and also [How to Provide an Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ok Thanks. I will give VBA a try.

Answer (score 0):

I would tackle this in the Edit Queries window of Power BI.  You should be able to achieve this by clicking around that window - no code is needed.

First  I would add 3 Conditional Columns to split your data out, e.g.

```
Computer Name
if [Column1] begins with Machine Then (column) Column1
```

Repeat for the other 2 columns.  Then select the **Computer Name** column and choose **Transform / Fill / Down**.  Finally select the **Computer Name** column and choose **Transform / Group By**.  Add aggregations for Max Status and Max Encryption.